# modelagem de banco de dados em php duvida

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

vou fazer um sistema para um colega so que estou com dúvida de como eu modelo o banco de dados

tenho uma tabela com tbl_leituraAtual tbl_leituraAnterior tbl_consumo tbl_fatorCorrecao = tbl_total

como eu faco esse total pegar o resultado desse calculo e inserir no banco de dados??? vou fazer em php

---

segue uma foto do sistema que vou fazer em excel qual a modelgaem que poderia utilizar para fazer esse sistema, sendo que quando a pessoa digitar o valor eu quero que ja preencha o campo valor total e depois ter um botao submit e salvar os dados no banco de dados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Primeiro não nomeie as tabelas com o prefixo TBL, se é uma tabela não precisa de TBL, fica uma forma mais limpa sua base de dados. Exemplos (LeituraAtual, LeituraAnterior,Consumo, FatorCorrecao).

Comment: Também não é legal utilizar CamelCase em nome de tabelas. Utilize o carácter _ (leitura_atual, leitura_anterior...)

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia ter apenas uma tabela "leituras". Onde iria armazenar a data, leitura, consumo, etc.
Ao montar a tabela com PHP fica mais fácil de fazer a consulta.

Comment: e como eu faria para adicionar varios linhas no banco?

Comment: Um simples INSERT. A tabela teria um campo autonumérico e você criaria um formulário em PHP para o seu cliente alimentar estes dados no banco.